# Как принято оформлять java веб-приложения?

Tags: java, java-ee, maven, tomcat

Собрал maven-оном веб-приложение, теперь war можно загрузить на любой веб-сервер, и все успешно задеплоится (1). Но в maven-е также есть возможность автоматически запускать сервер при помощи `mvn compile tomcat:run`, например (2).

В первом случае приложение не конфигурирует сервер, т.е. получается заказчик (допустим) сам должен будет его сконфигурировать перед запуском.

А во второй ситуации веб-приложение жестко привязано к какому-то серверу, что тоже нехорошо, а также необходимо наличие maven-а.

Так вот, как принято поступать в таких случаях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tomcat:run` - это, как правило, не для запуска приложения заказчиком, а для удобства разработчика.

Отдавать war вполне нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Заказчику отдается дистрибутив с вашим приложением (набор файликов в архиве\инсталлятор) + документация с исчерпывающей информацией по проекту. В каком формате? - согласовывается с заказчиком, либо если он пассивен - то на ваше усмотрение.

Maven нужен только разработчику, исключая случаи когда у вас есть система расширений и в документации вы рассказываете как писать к вашему софту те самые расширения (какие зависимости подключать в maven и т.п.).